# VSCode + PHP + xdebug + launch.json

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, launch

I have a Laravel project, and I have Xdebug working in VSCode.

But unfortunately I'm doing this in two steps. I want to combine it into one.

What I'm doing now, I write:

1. In cmd:

   ```
   php -S localhost:1000 -t public
   ```
2. Have a VSCode > debug > launch.json

   ```
   {
       "name": "Listen for XDebug",
       "type": "php",
       "request": "launch",
       "port": 9000
   },
   ```

How can I combine this into one task?

I've tried to create the 1. part as a task, but it didn't work.

task.json:

```
{
    "taskName": "PhpServe",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "php -S localhost:1000 -t public"
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "phpServe",
    "port": 9000
},
```

The PHP server starts up, and runs until I close it. After I close it Xdebug starts up. Not what I want.

How do I launch PHP server and xdebug at the same time?